# What wrong with my model?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I'm maked a tf2 workshop model , and i got a trouble

[image]

i'm new for modeling.
i'm try Solve the problem ,but doesn't work,who know what problem with my model and fix it ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share one of these pieces? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here https://pasteall.org/blend/71aa947078c84d02b3051d34c3f863c6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen to shade smooth, it will give these artefacts because it is trying to smooth between the orthogonal faces, unless you enable the *Auto Smooth* option which will allow you to choose the angle threshold. For the moment the *Auto Smooth* doesn't work because you have custom split normals (which determines the smoothness), perhaps due to the fact that it is an imported FBX or other format. So *Clear the Custom Split Normals Data*, enable the *Auto Smooth* option and set the right threshold:

[image]

Comment: looks like this are batter now thx. https://imgur.com/a/dajwqkT

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have some flipped normals. Try checking and recalculating their direction. (if you don't know about normals use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clzstqtN6YQ))

Comment: i'm tried ,but doesn't work .  https://imgur.com/a/vzXI9Ku